# What are those "._<filename>" files show in tar verbose output, but are not in the untarred directory?

Tags: terminal, command-line, file, compression

Some hidden files appear in the verbose output of `tar`, but then do not exist in the directory where the `tar` output is deposited. I am surprised by this because I thought working in *Terminal* command line was pretty brass tacks. What you see is always what you get?

```
/tmp$ tar xfv drills_grp01.tar
x Drills_grp01/
x Drills_grp01/._.DS_Store  // <-- what?
x Drills_grp01/.DS_Store
x Drills_grp01/._symm_hrz.txt  // <-- what?
x Drills_grp01/symm_hrz.txt
x Drills_grp01/._symm_vrt.txt  // <-- what?
x Drills_grp01/symm_vrt.txt
x Drills_grp01/._table_similarKj.txt  // <-- what is this?
x Drills_grp01/table_similarKj.txt
```

```
/tmp$ cd Drills_grp01
/tmp/Drills_grp01$ ls -a
.DS_Store     symm_hrz.txt     symm_vrt.txt     table_similarKj.txt
```

In the `ls -a` output, where are all those `._*` files I saw in the verbose output?

The life cycle of this tar file is:

1. files created in *Windows XP*, using *TextEdit*, saved to FAT32 file system.
2. compressed using the "*ZIP*" file format.
3. copied to MacOS (Extended / Jounaled).
4. decompressed using `unzip`
5. `tar cfv stuff.tar Stuff`
6. `bzip2 stuff.tar`

I'm curious.
Why does the verbose output of `tar xfv stuff.tar` not match the actual output?
Also, this means that the verbose output of **any** command in *Terminal* might not match the actual output? Trivial yes, but just something to be aware of.